# How to display live camera output in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios-camera

I want to display live camera output in a view controller. I start [with this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683863/front-camera-to-fill-circular-uiview).

This is what I did: I created a new View Controller in the Story board and connected it to the class below. The code and the output are below.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

//NOT WORKING - Unable to see Camera View in UIView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683863/front-camera-to-fill-circular-uiview

class TestVC: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{

var previewView : UIView!;
var boxView:UIView!;

//Camera Capture requiered properties
var videoDataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!;
var videoDataOutputQueue : dispatch_queue_t!;
var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!;
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
let session=AVCaptureSession();
var currentFrame:CIImage!
var done = false;


var cameraView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    cameraView.frame = CGRectMake(100, self.view.center.y-260, 568, 568)
    cameraView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26/255, green:188/255, blue:156/255, alpha:1)
    cameraView.layer.cornerRadius = 284
    cameraView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    cameraView.layer.borderWidth = 15
    cameraView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    cameraView.layer.masksToBounds = true



    var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size;
    self.previewView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height));
    self.previewView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(previewView);

    //Add a box view
    self.boxView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200));
    self.boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
    self.boxView.alpha = 0.3;

    self.view.addSubview(self.boxView);

    self.setupAVCapture();
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if !done {
        session.startRunning();
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
            return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
}


// AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate protocol and related methods
extension TestVC:  AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{

func setupAVCapture(){
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices();
    // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
    for device in devices {
        // Make sure this particular device supports video
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the front camera
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    beginSession()
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func beginSession(){
    var err : NSError? = nil
    var deviceInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err)
    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    if self.session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
        self.session.addInput(deviceInput)
    }

    self.videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    var rgbOutputSettings = [NSNumber(integer: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA):kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]
    self.videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true
    self.videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    self.videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue)
    if session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput){
        session.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
    }
    self.videoDataOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).enabled = true

    self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
    self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    var rootLayer :CALayer = self.cameraView.layer
    rootLayer.masksToBounds=true
    self.previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
    rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
    session.startRunning()

}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // do stuff here

}

// clean up AVCapture
func stopCamera(){
    session.stopRunning()
}

}
```

This is all I see in the output:

[image]

From [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683863/front-camera-to-fill-circular-uiview), I could not tell where the following piece of code should go? So, i placed it in the viewDidLoad. May be it needs to go elsewhere?

```
    cameraView.frame = CGRectMake(100, self.view.center.y-260, 568, 568)
    cameraView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26/255, green:188/255, blue:156/255, alpha:1)
    cameraView.layer.cornerRadius = 284
    cameraView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    cameraView.layer.borderWidth = 15
    cameraView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    cameraView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Regardless of if your code works, you wouldn't see a live feed - the simulator has no access to a camera.

Comment: I tried on a real device iPhone 5C, see the same green box

Answer (score 0):

Which `UIView` do you want to display the preview layer? `boxView` or `cameraView`? In your code, you add the preview layer to `cameraView`, but you only add `boxView` as a subview to your main view, so `cameraView` is never displayed.

If you want `cameraView`, change `self.view.addSubview(self.boxView)` to `self.view.addSubview(self.cameraView)` in `viewDidLoad`. If `boxView`, change `var rootLayer :CALayer = self.cameraView.layer` to `var rootLayer :CALayer = self.boxView.layer` in `beginSession`.

Either way will display the camera preview live, though the results are different since `boxView` and `cameraView` are set up differently.

**I think `boxView` is your intended one, so tl;dr: you added the preview layer to `cameraView` when you intended to add it to `boxView`.**

Answer (score 0):

You are close to success, but the wires are not well plugged.

Green box is **boxview**. if you want *camera preview* in **boxview**, you should add **preview** to **boxview**.